# Oracle update statement is getting inactive - Stale session issue

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, session

I'm facing an issue in production where an etl job is not getting completed in the update step. When i look at the sql the number of rows for updates is 0.

I use the same code base and ran the job in another prod mirror instance, the job got completed in the expected SLA. No stale states on the table or index stats on the target table.

When I look at the V$session rows, i see that the sql session has become inactive. I have killed the session and the session no longer appears in v$session view and when i restart the job, it is again going to that stale state. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't follow.  You say that a job is not completing.  That implies that it is still running.  You say that the SQL statement updated 0 rows which implies that it finished successfully.  You say that the session is now `INACTIVE` which means it is not doing anything at the moment which means that whatever SQL you executed completed.  I don't understand why you are saying that the SQL didn't complete.  I'm not sure what you mean by "stale state"-- you talk about "going to that stale state" and "stale states on the table" the latter of which I assume should refer to stats?

Answer (score 0):

INACTIVE means the session is not doing a thing..

you should explore the wait events...
if the wait event is waiting for networking - it means there's a but within your ETL code, if it is not - the wait event will tell you what's wrong.

you can get to it through V$SESSION pretty easily in versions 10 and above, just follow the column (and check if it is blocked by another session, the other common reason to something getting stuck.. - a blocking session)

if you want more help - please put over here the full record from V$SESSION, and all the hierarchy of the blocking sessions, if such exists...